# bash redirection to file adds unexpected 0A bytes

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I thought that if I redirected the output of **ls** to a file, the exact same sequence of characters that would otherwise have been sent to the console would get written to that file.

To test that, I create 3 files and then list them

```
$ touch a b c
$ ls
a  b  c
```

I now run **ls** again, this time redirecting to a file which I **cat**

```
$ ls > out
$ cat out
a
b
c
out
```

Unexpectedly, there is an 0A linefeed character between each filename in out

```
$ xxd out
00000000: 610a 620a 630a 6f75 740a                 a.b.c.out.
```

Piping the output of ls to xxd

```
$ ls | xxd
00000000: 610a 620a 630a 6f75 740a                 a.b.c.out.
```

the linefeeds are still present.

How did the 0A bytes get there? Does **ls** behave differently if it's being redirected or maybe the shell ignores linefeeds in certain circumstances?

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Comment: try `ls | xxd`.... (or `ls | cat`)

Comment: Despite relying on this behaviour for years I've never even noticed it: thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: piping to xxd is an interesting experiment, I've updated question a bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `ls` behaves differently if it is being redirected.  You can get the output you expect with `-x`:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/t
$ cd /tmp/t
$ touch a b c
$ ls | cat
a
b
c
$ ls -x | cat
a b c
$ ls --format=single-column
a
b
c
```

@GordonDavisson points us to the [POSIX spec for ls](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html), which reads

> The default format shall be to list one entry per line to standard output; the exceptions are to terminals or when one of the -C, -m, or -x options is specified. If the output is to a terminal, the format is implementation-defined.

Thus, at any rate in POSIX, it's the linewise output which is the 'norm'; the terminal output can be anything (although I've never seen anything except space-separation). Presumably this is to make it possible to iterate the response linewise.  I've also never noticed it, despite relying on it many times now I come to think about it!

### Implementation

And here it is in the source of one ls implementation, checking explicitly:

```c
    case LS_LS:
      /* This is for the `ls' program.  */
      if (isatty (STDOUT_FILENO))
        {
          format = many_per_line;
          /* See description of qmark_funny_chars, above.  */
          qmark_funny_chars = true;
        }
      else
        {
          format = one_per_line;
          qmark_funny_chars = false;
        }
      break;
```

[source](https://github.com/wertarbyte/coreutils/blob/master/src/ls.c#L1529-L1542)

Or in the current gnu coreutils:

```c
  format = (0 <= format_opt ? format_opt
            : ls_mode == LS_LS ? (stdout_isatty ()
                                  ? many_per_line : one_per_line)
            : ls_mode == LS_MULTI_COL ? many_per_line
            : /* ls_mode == LS_LONG_FORMAT */ long_format);
```

where `stdout_isatty` is defined as in the previous example.

[source](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/ls.c#L2263-L2267)

Comment: According to the [POSIX spec for `ls`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html): "The default format shall be to list one entry per line to standard output; the exceptions are to terminals or when one of the `-C`, `-m`, or `-x` options is specified. If the output is to a terminal, the format is implementation-defined." So the piped/redirected behavior, the "normal" behavior is technically not standardized.

Comment: @GordonDavisson thanks!  I'll add that in the answer (with attribution)